# How can i make the text appear only a single time in the TextView when retrieving it from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Here I have used addChildEventListener() method fetch the information from Firebase database under the method onChildAdded().

[image]

Please ignore `hold.add(chat);` as I was just getting the new child's items in an ArrayList.
**chat** is an object of class **helper** which consists of the name and message of a person.

But the problem that I am facing is that when I am appending the text I am recieving the data using `(chat.name+"\n"+chat.message+"\n\n)`
in a TextView it gets repeated.

[image]

**i.e I want it to be like**

Arunav
hi

Arunav
wssup bud

**Instead of :**

Arunav
hi

Arunav
wssup bud

Arunav
hi

Arunav
wssup bud

The messages get repeated each time I press the send button of my app.

**Thanks in Advance for helping,please forgive me if my question sounds dumb(its my first question on StackOverFlow and also I have very basic knowledge about Firebase Databases.
I strongly look forward for help.**

AGAIN THANKS.

Comment: Have you tried to use `setText()` and not `append()` for your data?

Comment: @AlexMamo  but  `setText()` will always replace the old data with the new one, I want the old data to be present with the new one  in the textView....btw Thanks for suggesting :)

Comment: So that's why you are getting that result, because every time you are appending data to the same TextView, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo  Yes ,I am appending the data to the same TextView.It has to show the old messages and the new ones too but what's happening is  that it shows the old data right from the beginning again with the new data.I want just the new data (in the new child)to be appended each time I press the send button of my app.Looking forward for help.